# Reset a selectpicker by clicking on a button

Tags: react-native

I created a functional component and I'm trying to reset or unselect a select picker by clicking on a button, I tried to use forceUpdate() but it didn't work.

I'm using a library called react-native-picker-select

My code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

export default function App() {
  const clean = () => {
    //reset picker
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={(value) => console.log("value")}
            placeholder={{
              label: 'Select'
            }}
            useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
            items={[
                { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
                { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
                { label: 'Option 3', value: '3' },
            ]}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={clean}>
              <Text>Clean</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Code running:

https://snack.expo.io/@rubend151/reset-picker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the control a controlled control by handling the `onValueChange` and setting the `value`.

According to a github [issue](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/40), setting the value to `null` should reset the selection, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. I set the placeholder item value to be 0 so we can rest it correctly.

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const clean = () => {
    //reset picker
    setValue(0) // <-- reset by setting the placeholder value.
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <RNPickerSelect
            onValueChange={(value) => setValue(value)} // <-- set  state manually.
            placeholder={{
              label: 'Select',
              value: 0
            }}
            useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
            items={[
                { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
                { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
                { label: 'Option 3', value: '3' },
            ]}
            value={value} // <-- use the value from state
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={clean}>
              <Text>Clean</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/_SweQ21QA